# リリース済iOSアプリのアップデート版ipaテストについて

Tags: ios, unity3d, iphone, cocos2d-x

リリース済iOSアプリをアップデートする必要がありましたので
アップデート版のipaファイルを実機にインストールしようとしたところ
インストールすることができませんでした。
※ipaはサーバー上にアップロードされている状態です。

実機にはリリース済のアプリがすでにインストールされておりましたので
もしかしたらこのリリース済アプリの影響と思いまして、
リリース済アプリを実機からアンインストール後にインストールしたら
インストールは無事にできましたが当然アンインストールしたのでデータは初期化されました。

データを引継した状態でアップデート版をテストしたいと思っていたのですが、
そもそも今の状態ではリリース済アプリを消さないと実機ではテストできないのでしょうか？

Comment: この情報だけでは回答できないと思います。例えば「今の状態」とはどういった状態でしょうか？質問者さんしか知らない情報は、質問を見ている方にはわかりません。また、作成されているアプリに関する詳しい情報も必要です。例えばアップデートしようとしているアプリのバージョンなどはインストール前のアプリから上げてあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score -2):

そのためのtestflightではないでしょうか？
実際にストアからアップデートした状況でテストできます
「testflight 使い方」で検索してみてください